# Code miss order when i translate Content inside Brackets, How to Fix it?

Tags: json

So here's the code in English :

"<8> <0 /> Free spins in a random game </8><8> <1 /> Casino Coins </8><8> <3 /> Loyalty Program XP </8><8> <4 /> Casino Bonus Balance </8><8> <5 /> Sports Free Bet </8><8> <6 /> Sports Bonus Balance </8><8> <7 /> Empty pocket. Skip turn</8>"

When i translate Content to Arabic, it automatically switches to the Right side of the editor. it's like mirroring the line from the end going up.

i have no clue how to keet the linees in the same order